# Can currently Mutinied buildings be targeted by Mutiny again?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

Can the second player's building which is currently under effect of the third player's Mutiny be targeted by my Mutiny? Will the current process (an offworld shipment, patent research or optimization) started by the third player continue in my favor?

I'm hoping to try and steal some ongoing research or shipments started on mutinied buildings to finish to my advantage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they can! You can re-mutiny buildings as many times as you like, if they are not temporarily defended or protected by a goon squad.

Comment: It's actually a nice early game strategy to mutiny a mutinied thermal power plant as then you're setting to rivals back.